# putting Javascript variable in other variable's definition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I'm writing a small plugin for ckeditor,

On a button firing, I'm trying to make the editor grab the raw html data to send to the server.
The correct syntax for this is

CKEDITOR.instances.div_id.getData(); 
or alternatively
CKEDITOR.instances[div_id].getData();

However this is grabbing a set named id, I want it to be relative to its parent id

```
var id = $(this).parent().attr("id");

var htmlcontent = CKEDITOR.instances.id.getData();
```

I'm realizing I don't know how to plug a var in that without thinking it's a function falling under CKEDITOR.  I should know this but it's just not coming to me.

Anecdotally that might not be a working parent id-grabber

**EDIT:**  To solve the CKeditor issue (which is not easy to find on the net)
CKeditor has some built in API to grab the container element id.

This is a working id-grabber for a CKeditor plugin and the data-grab syntax helped constructed by the answers below:

```
var id = editor.container.getId();
var htmlcontent = CKEDITOR.instances[id].getData();
```

as of 12/4/2014

Comment: You wrote example above - `CKEDITOR.instances[id].getData()`

Comment: @Cheery - You should turn that comment into an answer.

Comment: huh, if that's the answer, maybe the ckeditor problem runs a bit deeper.  But I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why doesn't `var htmlcontent = CKEDITOR.instances.id.getData();` work? The reason is that `id` is a variable holding the exact id stored previously in the line

```
var id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
```

This `id` variable holds something like "myElementId" in it. In order for you to use that string, you need to access the instances object using "bracket notation" (Related: [Working with Objects <sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)) if you do not specifically know the name of "myElementId" in advance.

As a result, this will work

```
var htmlcontent = CKEDITOR.instances[id].getData();
```

And would be similar to `CKEDITOR.instances.myElementId.getData()` if "myElementId" was the id of the parent element previously stored.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation.  That clears up the syntax confusion

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an `editor` object, you don't need to use `CKEDITOR.instances` at all, just use

```
editor.getData();
```